# Tomcat NotSerializableException

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, openam, opensso

I have implemented a security module with SAML library provided by OpenSSO, but my server is not closing properly and getting exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.identity.saml2.assertion.impl.AssertionImpl
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1014)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1671)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1077)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5655)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My calling classes are already serialized, how to fix this issue.

Comment: One Usually gets that exception when you try to save a object of a class that does not implement Serializable interface in a file. You say all your classes are serializable .. maybe you have a **HAS-A **relationship and that class is not serilizable

Comment: I was having a has-a relation that i removed, but still i am getting and its a library class, is their some other way to remove it.

Comment: Well if it is a library class then that could mean trouble but there is always a way out. Sorry I have never done an OpenSSO implementation so I can't help you.

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to serialize sessions or was Tomcat just configured that way?

Comment: No I am not serializing any sessions

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this seems to be that you are trying to store the received assertion in the HttpSession and your web application's web.xml has <distributable/> element that enables HTTP Session clustering in your container (which results in a serialization attempt).